# Can't access a class in another namespace c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
using cb_api.Models;

namespace cb_api.Controllers
{
    public class DetailsController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        ......
        .....
   }
}
```

`ApplicationDbContext` is a class inside Models; but I can't access it though I'm calling it's namespace.

```
namespace cb_api.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
        // 
        // If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
        // automatically whenever you change your model schema, please use data migrations.
        // For more information refer to the documentation:
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

        public ApplicationDbContext() : base("name=Context")
        {
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<cb_api.Models.Detail> Details { get; set; }
    }
}
```

That's `ApplicationDbContext` Class

Comment: Maybe because it is `private`?

Comment: Check the definition of that class. Presumably it's private or protected.

Comment: Please post the error message you're getting. Is the namespace in the same project? Is the class a nested class inside another class?

Comment: Post the outline of the ApplicationDbContext class, that's where the error begins.

Comment: CS0246 C# The type or namespace name 'ApplicationDbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Comment: The class is public and both are in the same project

Comment: If you explicitly call it with the namespace does it work?

Comment: If you add bogus code to ApplicationDbContext class, does it produce compiler errors? (as in, is the class actually compiled?)

Comment: In your project you should add a reference to EntityFramework

Comment: The error is actually generated in `Model.cs~
I'm getting an error that says : 
'The namespace cb_api already contains a definition for Model '

Comment: And that is a different error than what you started with.... You seem to have messed up your project structure, but there is not enough information here to help you.